# Best practice for naming Read model tables in a CQRS architecture?

Tags: cqrs

I'm new to the idea of CQRS, and as usual deciding how to name things is one of the hardest parts of the learning process.

If we are following the convention of 1 table per view in the read database for a CQRS application, how should we go about naming the tables for different views?

Let's say we have a number of different clients consuming the read model, should we name the tables based on the client and UI view that is consuming the data?

Is there no concern here that we are coupling our UI with the read model database and the webservices used for performing the queries? Or is this the very purpose of the CQRS architecture, to push all the complexity of aggregating data into the read model, rather than performing this work in the query webservices and client?

Can someone give some examples of the tablenames they use in their denormalized read models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > > Or is this the very purpose of the CQRS architecture, to push all the complexity of aggregating data into the read model, rather than performing this work in the query webservices and client?

Yes, that is the case.
You don't need to worry about coupling the read model to the UI because the read model is built to directly support UI needs.

As for examples:
My tables reflect path to a specific view they are built for.
Therefore I have for example AdminUsersList or AdminProductsEditPrices. The latter contains data for a web form accessible under /Admin/Products/Edit on the Prices tab.

I can think of naming your tables with some identifiers or whatever - as long as you can quickly resolve a connection between the table and the view.